# State affecting all elements with same name

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change the class of an element using the `onClick` event handler. When the `div` is clicked the `class` changes causing some css to change in turn. When I add another `div`, it assumes the same state as the first `div`.

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.startGambling = this.startGambling.bind(this);
        this.toggleClass = this.toggleClass.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            prize: '',
            tries: 0,
            isFlipped: false
        };
    }
    toggleClass() {
        this.setState({ isFlipped: true });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card-box" style={divStyle}>
                <div class="flip-card-inner" className={this.state.isFlipped ? 'flipped' : null} onClick={this.toggleClass}></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you "add another div"?

Comment: Yes, it does. You should probably be storing the state based on a unique id that you give each div

Comment: By add another div I mean copy and pasting the same div a second time

Comment: Your JSX code has mis-matched tags and is missing a closing curl-bracket

Comment: Edited to add closing bracket/element - please confirm that the change is as-intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State is not html-element-scoped. It is the state of the current Component.
Implement the `FlipCard` component and handle its flipped state within that component.

```js
class FlipCard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isFlipped: false
  }
  
  toggle = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isFlipped: !prevState.isFlipped
    }))

  }

  
  render(){
    const { isFlipped } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div
        onClick={this.toggle}
        className={isFlipped ? 'flipped' : ''}>
        Card
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const CardBox = () => (
  <article>
    <FlipCard />
    <FlipCard />
  </article>
);

ReactDOM.render(<CardBox />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.flipped {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach than @gazdagergo's answer but logic is the same. You need to track toggled state somewhere. If you don't need this toggled state anywhere else, you can keep it in its own components as @gazdagergo showed. But, for example, if you need to know how many items are toggled (just an example) you can keep the state in the parent component to share this info with another component.

```js
const cards = [
  { id: 1, name: "foo" },
  { id: 2, name: "bar" },
  { id: 3, name: "baz" }
];

const Card = ({ card, toggleClass, isFlipped }) => {
  const handleClick = () => toggleClass(card.id);
  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick} className={isFlipped[card.id] ? "flipped" : ""}>
      {card.name}
    </div>
  );
};

class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleClass = this.toggleClass.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      prize: "",
      tries: 0,
      isFlipped: {}
    };
  }

  toggleClass(id) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isFlipped: { ...state.isFlipped, [id]: !state.isFlipped[id] }
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {cards.map(card => (
          <Card
            key={card.id}
            card={card}
            toggleClass={this.toggleClass}
            isFlipped={this.state.isFlipped}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Content />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.flipped {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

In the example, I assumed that card items have a unique id but you can do that with indexes also. Your `isFlipped` state is not a boolean anymore, it is an object and keeps the flipped ids.